# jQuery-Validation-Engine validation two field range

Tags: jquery, validation

I use jQuery Validation Engine for my form validation here is link for demo :

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I have tow text box, `minage` is 25 value and `maxage` is 15.

I want validate that

minage must not be greater then maxage 
or 
maxage  must not be less then minage.

```
<input name="minage" type="text" id="minage">
<input name="maxage" type="text" id="maxage">
```

If any validation is there then please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, "minage is 25" and "maxage is 15", by chance, should it be the other way around? "minage is 15" and "maxage is 25"?

Comment: User can input any range but (minage must not be greater then maxage or maxage must not be less then minage) this validate is require